# Pyspark substring with values from another table

Tags: join, pyspark, substring, lookup

Pyspark: I have two dataframes.  First one is one column containing a long string.  Second dataframe is a lookup dataframe holding some values that indicate some substring start and ends.  I'd like to use the second data frame to split up the first and have a resultant dataframe with the original data and the string split values:

Dataframe A:

| Data |
| --- |
| 000 456 9b |
| 876 998 1c |

Dataframe B:

| Description | Start | End | Length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| City | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| Country | 5 | 7 | 3 |
| IheartSpark | 9 | 10 | 2 |

The result would be this:

| Data | City | Country | IheartSpark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 000 456 9b | 000 | 456 | 9b |
| 876 998 1c | 876 | 998 | 1c |

Dataframe b is only 30 rows or so and i was thinking of broadcasting this if possible (this will run in a cluster).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with **`crossJoin`** and **`pivot`** functions to get the desired output.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()
#+----------+
#|      Data|
#+----------+
#|000 456 9b|
#|876 998 1c|
#+----------+

df1.show()
#+-----------+-----+---+------+
#|      Descr|start|end|length|
#+-----------+-----+---+------+
#|       City|    1|  3|     3|
#|    Country|    5|  7|     3|
#|IheartSpark|    9| 10|     2|
#+-----------+-----+---+------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.crossJoin(broadcast(df1)).\
withColumn("nn",expr("""substring(Data,start,length)""")).\
groupBy("Data").\
pivot("Descr").\
agg(first(col("nn"))).\
show()
#+----------+----+-------+-----------+
#|      Data|City|Country|IheartSpark|
#+----------+----+-------+-----------+
#|000 456 9b| 000|    456|         9b|
#|876 998 1c| 876|    998|         1c|
#+----------+----+-------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Shu, do you see any performance problems with this approach if Dataframe A is large (200GB or so) ?